# Write 2-complement byte java

Tags: java, binary

In java if you want to write a number using its binary representation you can write

```
 System.out.println(0b0001);
```

Which will print 1

If you write specificaly 32 bits it will interpret it as a 2-complement ie:

```
System.out.println(0b11111111111111111111111111111110);
```

Will print -2

How could i write 2-complement for number that are not 32-bits? (specifically for number bigger than 32 bit, eg long)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put an `L` after it indicating it is a `long`.

```
long val  =0b111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111101100L;
System.out.println(val);
```

Prints

```
-20
```

Comment: Yes i know how to do long but that is not 2-complement that just the number, if it was 2-complement encoded it would be negative as it start with 1

Comment: I modified my answer.